# Automatic - Cold engine uses tons of gas to move

Tags: vw, car, golf, cold-start

so I recently purchased a Volkswagen Golf MK4, 2002, Automatic.
1.6 SR running on Gasoline and LPG.

When I start the car in the morning (Usually 2-7 Celcius outside),starting it with Gasoline ofcourse,  it takes a few seconds but it's all fine.

However, when I put it in drive, press the pedal a little bit, it barely moves, as if it's stuck in another gear (like limp mode, but it isn't..)

When I give it a bit more gas, it starts moving, no problems, but when I look at the current L/h it goes up to 70-80.

This does not occur after the car has been running for atleast a minute..- meaning that if I come to a full stop around the corner, and start driving, it doesn't do "this" anymore.

Any ideas?

Update:
I threw the car way and got myself a decent car. The car was in limp mode pretty much 90% of the time.

- Blew head gasket
- Leaking and burning oil
- Burned tons of engine coolant when Gasket blew
- Ran on 2-3 cylinders instead of 4..

I recommend you get another car before it shows all these signs because mine went straight to the junkyard after.

Comment: When "it barely moves" is the engine revving a lot, but it is as though the engine is not connected to the gearbox properly?

Comment: @HandyHowie Yeah, Ofcourse I don't rev it alot, because I know it's still cold, but indeed it feels like it's not connected to the gearbox

Comment: Sorry, you miss-understand.  I was asking if the engine revs up more than you would expect for the speed you are going.

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes yes, sorry. Correct, it revs more than it should for the speeds it's going.

Comment: It'd rev up to 2.5-3k , using around 70L/h going only 5-10 km/h max

Comment: It sounds like the fluid in the torque converter is initially low and it is taking a minute or so for the pump to fill it with fluid.  See if anyone else has any thoughts.

Comment: @HandyHowie That actually sounds like a potentional answer. It feels like either the fluid to low, or a bit solid-ish? For example a bit frozen? I'm not sure if that's even possible however. Also, sometimes it takes a bit long to get the engine to actually start. It'd take a second or 10-15 to actually start up. It usually goes faster when I tap the pedal a bit.

Comment: When is the last time you changed your transmission fluid? I'd change the fluid and see if things improve.

Comment: Changing the fluid and filter sounds like a good idea.